# OutOfMemory exception when loading xml in C#

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

I get outofmemory exception when execute below code for many nodes in a tree view.

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(vConditionPaths.InputLogXmlPath);
_inputItenLogDoc.Load(reader);
reader.Close();
```

Where `vConditionPaths.InputLogXmlPath` is path of the xml and `_inputItenLogDoc` is the `XmlDocument` which is declared as local variable in a class.

Please help

Comment: Fix it? How many nodes are there. 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: An `OutOfMemoryException` is fairly self explanatory. What line is the exception thrown on?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your xml file is to big to be handled by the XmlTextReader. (Because XmlTextReader will try to read the whole xml file at once)

You could try a SAX parser which does a sequential parsing. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML

See http://saxdotnet.sourceforge.net/

for a c# solution. As far as I know there is no native .net framework sax parser solution. Maybe anyone else does know a newer sax parser for .net? I am very interested :-)